# How to pass array from codeigniter Helper to contorller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i am working on a notification system where i need to use helper to count and list all the alerts.
When i try to `print_r` from the helper i am able to see all the items in the array, whereas when i do the same thing form my controller i can only see one item. 
for example:..

### **Notifications helper**

```
  function notification_list($ci)
  {
    $userID = $ci->session->userdata('user_id');
    $getNotifications =$ci->model_notifications->get_all(array("UserID"=>$userID), 'usernotifications');

    foreach ($getNotifications as $notifications)
    {           
      $ListNotifications =$ci->model_notifications->get_all(array("ID"=>$notifications->NotificationID), 'notifications');
      print_r($ListNotifications);
    }
  }
```

### the output is

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [Title] => Demo Notification [Message] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In volutpat dui quis neque fringilla semper. Praesent vel sollicitudin leo. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur quis sapien a metus facilisis malesuada. Nulla vitae quam vel turpis viverra pharetra fringilla ac urna. Vivamus hendrerit a quam ac hendrerit. [Type] => 2 [ActionID] => 3 [StatusID] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2 [Title] => Demo Alert [Message] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In volutpat dui quis neque fringilla semper. Praesent vel sollicitudin leo. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur quis sapien a metus facilisis malesuada. [Type] => 1 [ActionID] => 3 [StatusID] => 1 ) )
```

but when i return `$ListNotifications` and `print_r(notification_list($ci))` from my controller i can see only one result. something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [Title] => Demo Notification [Message] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In volutpat dui quis neque fringilla semper. Praesent vel sollicitudin leo. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur quis sapien a metus facilisis malesuada. Nulla vitae quam vel turpis viverra pharetra fringilla ac urna. Vivamus hendrerit a quam ac hendrerit. [Type] => 2 [ActionID] => 3 [StatusID] => 1 ) )
```

what do you guys think i am doing wrong here. is there a way i can return an array from my helper to my controller?

Thanks
Max

Comment: Use `print_r(notification_list())` from controller

Comment: Proof read you question first code not formatted correct.

Comment: Thanks, i was returning the array from the loop as a result the loop was disconnected.